# Comprehensive reference book for syntax and style

Tags: style, resources

I am searching for a good comprehensive (up-to-date) reference that covers not only English grammar and syntax (from an **advanced** standpoint) but also (actually *mainly*) matters of intrinsically stylistic nature that are relevant to writers. Which such volume would you recommend? Recommendations might be divided as follows:

- general writing;
- "literary artwork";
- sciences and mathematics.

Please, support your claims with solid background. Thank you.

---

Note: this question is ment as a [big-list]

Comment: We already have [many questions asking for reference books about writing](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources). For books specifically about grammar, you can find several examples [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools). I hope this helps.

Comment: @NeilFein It surely does help. Thank you very much for pointing out these threds :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For American English, [Strunk & White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) or [Garner's MAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garner's_Modern_American_Usage).

For British English, [Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage) (updated edition) or style guides from the [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a), [Economist](http://www.economist.com/styleguide/introduction) or [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/news-style-guide).

[image: xkcd: Strunk and White]
Source: http://xkcd.com/923/ (image licensed CC BY-NC 2.5)

See also: ['Style guide' @ Wikipedia (scroll down for a big list)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide)